Windows Memory Usage much larger than sum of managed heap objects
I have a proces which comsunes around 16GB of memory. I have made a dump file which has a size of around 20GB. When i analyse the file i get a total size of 1,7GB of used managed memory by my objects.
My question is: What is taking up the rest of the memory?
I tried to identify free objects with windbg, but that are only 400MB.
WinDbg says:
Heap     14.533GB
unknown  11.753GB
Visual Studio says: 1,7GB
Can there be so much unmanaged memory?

A process might not only hold managed memory. You will have to learn native memory analysis techniques as well.

"comsunes around 16GB of memory" which measure? There are multiple measures that are different! Eg. Working Set is allocated physical memory vs Virtual Address Space is the number of virtual memory addresses allocated (allocating an address does not mean there is any physical or virtual memory allocated).

Also, more specifically, the managed heaps include memory allocated to the process that is not currently in use (but may have been in the past). Eg. after a collection parts of the managed heaps will be now available for new allocation.

WinDbg says: Heap 14.533GB, unknown 11.753GB
Visual Studio says: 1,7GB
Can there be so much unmanaged memory?

Of course there can be that much "" memory. The debugger seldom lies. Trust it.

What can be the difference between Heap 14.533GB and 1,7GB Managed Memory? How can I analyze this?

Before you analyze the memory, you should ask yourself why you think this is unusual. Maybe for your app it's totally normal to consume 16 GB of memory. If you load 1000 Bitmaps in order to make a video out of it, that's totally fine, I guess. How much memory do you expect, or what it your memory goal and why?

If you suspect a memory leak, you should try to reproduce it. You should be able to repeat an action which increases memory. In a .NET application, you typically need to look out for managed objects that hold unmanaged resources. If done right, those classes implement the IDisposable pattern, but maybe you forgot to call Dispose(). You don't analyze that in WinDbg but a .NET specific tool like JetBrains dotMemory.

If you dispose 400 MB of .NET objects, that can release 16 GB of unmanaged resources (depending on the type of the managed objects).
